# How to write this SQL in HQL or using Criteria?

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

Is there any way to rewrite equivalent of below SQL in Hbernate HQL or Using Hibernate Criteria (or DetachedCriteria)? It should return single record from database.

And Which one is advisable using HQL or Criteria or just native SQL?

```
Select * from X where x.name="name" and x.date =(select max(x.date) from X where x.name="name" )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Model from X model where model.name="name" and 
model.date =(select max(model1.date) from X model1 where model1 .name="name" )
```

or

If you are using `Hibernate3`
  use `order by date` and then q`uery.setMaxResults()` really is your only option.

If you are using `Hibernate2` then you can use `LIMIT`

Answer (score 0):

Equalent Hibernate:
from Xpojo x where x.name="name" and x.date =(select max(y.date) from Xpojo y where y.name="name" )
It will work for any DB.